# Implement a parameterized interface method that has a parameterized class argument with a concrete class

Tags: java, generics

```
public interface AssignmentInterface<T> {

    MetadataFieldInterface<T> getField();
    
    void setField(MetadataFieldInterface<T> field);
}
```

```
public class DatasetAcquisitionAssignment implements AssignmentInterface<DatasetAcquisition>  {

    @Override
    public DatasetAcquisitionMetadataField getField() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void setField(DatasetAcquisitionMetadataField field) { // HERE !!! 
        ...
    }
```

```
public enum DatasetAcquisitionMetadataField implements MetadataFieldInterface<DatasetAcquisition> { ... }
```

Eclipse error : **The method setField(DatasetAcquisitionMetadataField) of type DatasetAcquisitionAssignment must override or implement a supertype method**

Compilation fails as well

Using `public void setField(MetadataFieldInterface<DatasetAcquisition> field) {}` instead fixes the problem (but leads to further problems at runtime, with jackson)

What can I do so I can use DatasetAcquisitionMetadataField as the concrete method argument ?

Comment: what is `DatasetAcquisition` and `DatasetAcquisitionMetadataField`? can you post an example that _compiles_?

Comment: @eugene using MetadataFieldInterface<DatasetAcquisition> as setField argument type compiles

Comment: @eugene I added the definition of DatasetAcquisitionMetadataField

Comment: from the interface declaration. `setField` accepts a (any)`MetadataFieldInterface<DatasetAcquisition>`, so it can, for example, be called with an instance of `Test implements MetadataFieldInterface<DatasetAcquisition>` - but the implementation does ONLY accept `DatasetAcquisitionMetadataField`, NOT `Test` neither any other class implementing `MetadataFieldInterface<DatasetAcquisition>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your interface to?

```
public interface AssignmentInterface<T, R extends MetadataFieldInterface<T>>{

    MetadataFieldInterface<T> getField();

    void setField(R field);
}
```